# Cant insert text - a msg that the element is not visible is displayed

Tags: selenium

I run automation on a site that after I click on a button and a screen of PayPal is opened for  inserting details. The PayPal is opened in another tab. I added a syntax that move the testing to the relevant tab and then I insert a syntax that checks that the "email input" field exists (to check that it is really goes to the correct tab) - and the result of this test  :- field exists.
Then - I add a syntax for the same field to insert the email and the test is failed - the text is not inserted and there is a msg that the field is not visible.
No need to do scroll because the filed is in the top of the screen.
What can I do in this case?

This is the relevant code:

```
    String oldTab = driver.getWindowHandle();

    comOps.clickOrChose(PLS.buyButton);
    Thread.sleep(4000);

    ArrayList<String> newTab = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());

    newTab.remove(oldTab);  
    driver.switchTo().window(newTab.get(0)); 

    comOps.verifyElementExist(PLP.payPalEmail);

    comOps.insertText(PLP.payPalEmail, "paypal-buyer@makeitleo.com");
```

Comment: Seems like you have class as `comOps` which performs some of the common actions. I think the element may not visible or may be hidden. In that case, you may need to check that first. Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: Yes. This is what i received when im trying to insert the text. Element is not visible. What can I do?

Comment: Can you check whether element is visible after scroll?

Comment: No need scroll, it is on the top of the page....

Comment: is your method `verifyElementExist` take care of hidden element? Please add error console to your question

Comment: Now i user a different method to do it simple for checking: driver.findElement(By.xpath.....).sendkey("nnnn"); And i received this msg about the invisible.

Comment: post error log of error and please edit your question

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this error message is that the element apparently exists but is not visible when you try to enter text to it. There are a lot of possible reasons why the element is not visible.

Given that a new tab is opended a probable reason is that the page (and its elements) is still loading. If this is the case, you need to wait for the visiblity of the element, e.g. using this piece of code (before inserting text):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 300); //waiting up to 5 minutes    
ExpectedCondition<WebElement> condition = 
    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(PLP.payPalEmail);
wait.until(condition);
```

Note: that this solution assumes that `PLP.payPalEmail` is of type `org.openqa.selenium.WebElement`. If it is of type `org.openqa.selenium.By` use `visibilityOfElementLocated(By locator)`.

Telling from your code snippet, I assume that `comOps` is an object of a class wrapping all Selenium actions. So, it is a good idea to place the above code in some method inside that class which could look like this:

```
public void verifyElementVisible(WebElement element) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 300); //ToDo: use configurable timeout    
    ExpectedCondition<WebElement> condition = 
    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element);
    wait.until(condition);
}
```

and call it like this

`comOps.verifyElementVisible(PLP.payPalEmail);`